# Property of spectrum

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be an operator on $X$ with non-empty resolvent set, and let $\lambda _0 \in \rho (T)$. Show that
 $\lambda \in  \sigma (T)$ if and only if $(\lambda _0 − λ)^{−1} \in  \sigma(R(\lambda _0; T))$

I tried to prove it using definiton of resolvent set but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show us the work you did and how far you got using the definition of resolvent set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$(\lambda_0-\lambda)^{-1}-R(\lambda_0;T)=(\lambda_0-\lambda)^{-1}(\lambda-T)R(\lambda_0;T).$$

Comment: Ok, I think it helped me.

$ \Rightarrow $

So we know that $\lambda \in \sigma (T)$. It follows that $\nexists \ (T-\lambda I)^{-1}$. We have to show that $\nexists \ (R(\lambda _0;T)-(\lambda _0 -\lambda)^{-1})^{-1}$

From your hint the right hand side is not invertible because of $\lambda I-T$

$\Leftarrow$

$R(\lambda _0, T)$ is invertible and also $(\lambda _0 - \lambda )^{-1}$ but $(\lambda _0 - \lambda )^{-1}(\lambda - T)R(\lambda _0;T)$ is not invertible. It follows that $(\lambda - T)$ is not invertible so $\lambda \in \sigma (T)$

It's correct?

Comment: @KrzysztofB Yes, you're right. From the expression. A shorter way: LHS is invertible iff RHS is invertible iff $(\lambda -T)$ is invertible. And this is what you want to show.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your hint was very helpful.